# What is the difference between "회사원" and "회사 사람"?

Tags: nouns

Both '회사원' and '회사 사람' roughly translates to "company person" or a person working for a company. But there seems to be a subtle difference that I can't quite pin point. How are those two different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'회사원' and '회사 사람' have a completely different connotation. The former usually means 'company employee' or 'company staff' and you never use '회사 사람' to mean that.

'회사 사람' is literally translated to a 'company person' and used when trying to  identify another person as a member of the same or different company. For example:

> 김철수씨는 당신과 같은 회사 사람 아니예요? Isn't Mr. Kim Cheolsu a member of your company?
>
> 아니요. 김철수씨는 다른 회사 사람이에요. No, Mr. Kim Cheolsu is a member of a different company.
>
> 김철수씨는 우리 회사 사람이에요. Mr. Kim Cheolsu is a member of our company.

'회사분' is an honorific word for '회사 사람'

> 은행원 (bank employee) vs 은행 사람 (X)
>
> 공작원 (operative or spy) vs 공작 사람 (X)
>
> 종업원 (employee) vs 종업 사람 (X)
>
> 사무원 (office worker) vs 사무 사람 (X)
>
> 교직원 (school employee, teaching staff) vs 교직 사람 (X)